# WordPress - I can't login - Something wrong with the wp_users table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I can't login to the admin dashboard. When I go to localhost/nutri/wp-admin, it automatically redirects me to:

```
http://localhost/nutri/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fnutri%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

and when I try to login, it just redirects me back to that same URL. It doesn't give any error message on the screen. If I try to login with incorrect details, then it does give the usual incorrect username or password message, so this isn't a problem with the login details.

WP_DEBUG is on but no error messages are appearing on the screen. But a new error appears in error_log.php every time I try to login:

> [01-Oct-2016 22:01:31 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (31, 'session_tokens', 'a:1:{s:64:\"430df13e6700f4ec995ca5f4eb5901886b39db5225975bcef392002b27173629\";a:4:{s:10:\"expiration\";i:1475532091;s:2:\"ip\";s:3:\"::1\";s:2:\"ua\";s:73:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0\";s:5:\"login\";i:1475359291;}}') made by wp_signon, wp_set_auth_cookie, WP_Session_Tokens->create, WP_Session_Tokens->update, WP_User_Meta_Session_Tokens->update_session, WP_User_Meta_Session_Tokens->update_sessions, update_user_meta, update_metadata, add_metadata

Yesterday I added a new member through the admin dashboard, and today when I went into the wp_users table in phpmyadmin (to try manually resetting my password) and I noticed that the new user I entered had an ID of 0. I deleted that row. Today I tried registering a new account through my registration form. The new account again had an ID of 0. If I delete it, and register a new user, the same thing happens:
https://i.gyazo.com/c3daabb414f620f1b6c11c1d199a1d39.png

If I try adding a new user without deleting the ID=0 account, I get this error message on screen:

> WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
>   INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_pass`, `user_email`, `user_url`, `user_nicename`, `display_name`, `user_registered`, `user_login`) VALUES ('$P$Bj1pCG4T8VksjjeeD.dx8Qu0p9l7RT.', 'root@ftes.com', '', 'rootftes-com', 'root@ftes.com', '2016-10-01 21:48:42', 'root@ftes.com')

I tried disabling all plugins and I tried deactivating the theme but none of that worked. I tried installing a fresh version of wp-login.php.

So the issue is something to do with the wp_users table but I don't know how to further diagnose or fix this. It works fine on the live server, but I'm afraid to upload my changes now in case it breaks the live site.

Comment: Can you gain access to the db using phpmyadmin or a mysql client?

Comment: Yeah I can access the DB from PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's the DB per say, it almost sounds like something is trying (badly) to inject a new user when you login.

If you've access to the source files try searching for the text  wp_create_user
and
 INSERT INTO wp_users
Just to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting both the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables, and importing them from backups made from the live server. The problem was with the usermeta table.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem but can't seem to delete the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160414/wordpress-database-error-table-databasename-wp-users-doesnt-exist-select

Answer (score 1):

you could import (and replace) the whole wp_users table from the live server

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't work. Still can't log in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try creating fresh tables, then when you go to /wp-admin it will (hopefully) prompt you to register a new user.

To do this run the following queries in phpmyadmin then go to http://localhost/nutri/wp-login.php

you could also try renaming wp-config.php, that way when you go to /wp-admin, it will take you through the initialisation process.

```
CREATE TABLE users_old LIKE wp_users;
CREATE TABLE usermeta_old LIKE wp_usermeta;
INSERT INTO users_old SELECT * FROM wp_users;
INSERT INTO usermeta_old SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta;
DELETE FROM wp_users;
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta;
```