# WordPress Database Error: [Table 'databasename.wp_users' doesn't exist] SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = 'Username'

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I was developing a WordPress theme locally on a Mac (OSx Sierra) using XAMPP. It was set up so that when I typed `localhost/ThemeName` into the URL, I was taken to my site. I restarted my computer after installing some updates and now when I go to `localhost/ThemeName` I get this:

[image]

Obviously I don't want another WordPress installation - it's already installed. After checking around, I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817501/wordpress-i-cant-login-something-wrong-with-the-wp-users-table) which seems to address a similar problem. He suggests 'deleting both the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables', but I don't know what he means by 'importing them from backups made from the live server'.

In phpMyAdmin, my database looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I get an error message for every table within the Database for my theme - `wp_commentmeta`, `wp_comments`, `wp_links`, `wp_options`, etc. - if I click on any of those I get a message saying that the table doesn't exist. I tried to 'drop' the `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta` tables but they're still there and now the 'drop' option is actually gone:

[image]

Please help if you know what to do, thanks!

**EDIT**: After going ahead and entering Site Title, Email Address, and hitting Install WordPress, I received thousands of error messages:

[image][image][image]

And so on and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Apache and switched to a different internet connection at a different location. I can go to localhost/MyWPTheme and it works just fine.

Comment: Hi, I'd be really grateful if you could expand on this? I'm having the exact same problem. It looks like I'll have to reinstall Wordpress and start again with my site - which is fine but what if it keeps happening? I need to know I can fix it if it happens again.

Comment: Hi - do you still need help with this? Sorry I've been off SO for a couple of weeks. I can take a look if you still need help. I remember the issue being fixed just by restarting Apache.

Comment: Hi, thanks for coming back to me. I sorted it in the end - had to start again from scratch, but no big deal. Any thoughts on this one - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45333612/3521315  ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and run:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Then, run your Wordpress installation normally.