# Wordpress - correct php link for images in media library

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm finalising a wp site I've built on my local server and removing all localhost links. I've added all the_permalink tags for pages but I'm struggling with the links for my `img` tags. I've tried `<?php get_attached_media( 'ID' ) ?>` and I've tried `<? php wp_get_attachment_link() ?>` and `<? php wp_get_attachment_image() ?>` but none seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? This is the code in my header file, for example, so its all standard code -

**header.php**

```
<div class="left-header">
            <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" style="width:250px;height:30px;">
        </div>
    <div class="right-header">
         <div class="right-header-top">
            <div id="contact">
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/phone.png">
                <p>0113 220 5265</p>
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/email.png">
                <p>hello@media.co.uk</p>
            </div>
```

Pretty much all the images I'm looking to change are in `img` tags.I'm sure this is a straightforward fix but I'm having a real brain freeze at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `<?php echo home_url(); ?>`, for example:

```
<img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/phone.png">
```

Comment: Thanks. What about other pages - like products or about - do you just replace home?

Comment: You can, yes. But very often a lot of this is in the database, and you can replace it in one go (in the sql code) when you export/import the database. Only the links in the template files have to be changed (but probably you know that anyway)

Comment: I would love to know how to do that.

Comment: The easy way is to use a plugin like "WP Migrate", but you can also simply export the complete DB in phpmyadmin, open the resulting sql file in any text editor, do a search/replace and then import it in the empty DB on the production server

Comment: I haven't exported the database as the site is for a client and they have their own database/server set up. This is one reason why this issue was raised - I'm not used to WP/php so I sent everything with absolute URLs rather than relative - so I'm having to redo all the links.

Comment: I'd love to know how its all done in one go, though. I've seen something via a google search where someone has placed a filter array in their functions.php file, not sure if it will work though.

Comment: you won't get around handling the database migration - wordpress is based on that, and not only the content that your clients will add, but basically a good part of the system setup. But that's definitely too much for a Stackoverflow question/answer scenario - you should look for some good tutorials, articles, books, DVDs, whatever

Comment: @Johannes Apologies - had to go out a couple of hours ago and just seen your replies. Many thanks.

Comment: @Johannes One last question from me then I'll leave you alone (promise!) Regarding the database migration does the duplicator plugin, which is what I'm using, deal with that as well or do I need to handle that separately?

Comment: I have to admit that I don't know Duplicator, so I can't tell you for sure. But I had a short look at it, and it seems it does all that - looks good, I have to try using it one of these days. But I would not expect that it converts absolute links in template files...

Comment: @Johannes No, it doesn't do the links so I've gone back through everything tonight and changed them. It was the database migration I was worried about and it seems to handle that so, all good.